# Double quotes in Oracle sql string

Tags: oracle

For the Oracle sql, the field name needs to be like this: `"DateOfCreation"` (with quotes inside the sql string), then I put the + CHR(34) and it looks like this `""DateOfCreation""` (with two double quotes).
I've tried with REPLACE, too, and it doesn't work!

That's how it's supposed to be:
`Select * from VW_Details where to_date("DateOfCreation", 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') > to_date('01/09/2023 10:41:07', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`

Comment: Unclear : What exactly are you doing ? What is the starting string ?

Comment: Might be better asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You are showing a SQL string that contains double quotes. So what? Why are you trying to insert CHR(34)? Why are you trying to replace something here? Why not use the string as is?

Comment: You only need double quotes if the entity name is a reserved word. That is not the case for you, so delete the double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

> For the Oracle sql, the field name needs to be like this: "DateOfCreation" (with quotes inside the sql string)

Quoting the [Database Object Names and Qualifiers documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49):

> #### Database Object Naming Rules
>
> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent the name of an object with a quoted identifier or a nonquoted identifier.
>
> - A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.
> - A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.
>
> You can use either quoted or nonquoted identifiers to name any database object.

and:

> 7. Nonquoted identifiers can only contain alphanumeric characters from your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($), and pound sign (#). Database links can also contain periods (.) and "at" signs (@). Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in nonquoted identifiers.
>
>    Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0).

The last sentence of rule #7 clearly states that double quotes **CANNOT** be part of an identifier (either quoted or unquoted); therefore, what you are asking is impossible as the naming rules forbids it.

---

You can name the column `DateOfCreation`, in mixed case, and assuming it has the `DATE` data type then you can use a quoted identifier to access it with the query:

```sql
Select *
from   VW_Details
where  "DateOfCreation" > to_date('01/09/2023 10:41:07', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

*Note: **NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on a column that is already a `DATE`. At best, it is a pointless function call that does effectively nothing, and, at worst, causes the query to raise an exception or give an unexpected result.*

But you cannot call a column `"DateOfCreation"` and trying to use double quotes inside an identifier is syntactically invalid:

```sql
Select *
from   VW_Details
where  ""DateOfCreation"" > to_date('01/09/2023 10:41:07', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Will fail with `ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier`.